# Make view fixed to top when it passes the top

Tags: android, scrollview

Sorry if the title isn't really clear but I don't know what the effect is called. It will get clear with some screenshots..

I have a homescreen with a search container on the top and a list of houses at the bottom.
The whole homescreen is a scrollview and when the 'Panden in uw buurt' textview passes the top off the screen I want it to be fixed.

start screen:

[image]

what I want to achieve if user scrolls down:

[image]

This is my xml layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/quick_search_view"
        layout="@layout/view_quick_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/quick_search_view"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/house1" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/house2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/quick_search_view"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:background="@drawable/triangle_indicator"
        android:rotation="180" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

follow the steps-

1. Exclude 'Panden in uw buurt' from your "@layout/view_quick_search".[Header also if its not actionBar]
2. Put it below "@+id/quick_search_view".
3. set/add Listeners for Scrolling.
4. OnScroll set visibility of "@+id/quick_search_view" gone/visible OR set
   translate animation.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution : [here](https://code.google.com/p/romannurik-code/source/browse/misc/scrolltricks#scrolltricks%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fexample%2Fandroid%2Fscrolltricks)

The stickyfragment and observableScrollView did the job!